# Append a column to a file based on line number

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, paste

I have a list of numbers which i would like to add to the end of another file as the final column:

```
1:.196
5:.964
6:.172
```

The numbers in front (1,5 and 6) indicate at which line the numbers have to be appended in the target file, so that the first line ends with `.196`, the fifth with `.964` and so on. The usual `paste file1 file2` does not take the line numbers into account and simply adds `1:.196` at the end of the first line and `.964` at the end of the second instead of the fifth. Any ideas how to do it the right way?

Expected would be something like this:

```
Lorem Ipsum 1238 Dolor Sit 4559.196
Lorem Ipsum 4589 Sit elitr 1234
Lorem Ipsum 3215 Dolor Sit 5678
Lorem Ipsum 7825 Dolor Sit 9101
Lorem Ipsum 1865 Dolor Sit 1234.964
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
# create two test files
printf '%s\n' one two three four five six > target_file
printf '%s\n' 1:.196 5:.964 6:.172 > numbers

awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next } FNR in a{ $0=$0 a[FNR] }1' numbers target_file
```

Output:

```
one.196
two
three
four
five.964
six.172
```

---

Explanation:

```
awk -F':' '      # use `:` as input field separator
  NR==FNR {      # if this is the first file, then...
    a[$1]=$2     # save the second field in array `a` using the first field as index
    next         # stop processing, continue with the next line
  }                         
  FNR in a {     # test if the current line number is present in the array
    $0=$0 a[FNR] # append array value to the current line 
  }
  1              # print the current line
' numbers target_file
```

Comment: `FNR in a{ $0=$0 a[FNR] }1` can just be `{print $0 a[FNR]}` unless that 2nd file is extremely massive and so you don't want to create an entry in `a[]` for every line of it as you read it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/:/s:$:/;s/$/:/' nums_file |
  sed -f - file
```

Explanation:

```
° use the number file to create the sed commands to operate on the actual data
° Pass these sed commands over the pipe and use sed to apply them on the data file.
```